# Haskell representation for spider solitaire tableau

Tags: haskell, data-structures, indexing

I am working on a Haskell implementation of a Spider Solitaire player, both as an exercise in learning Haskell and trying to find a good player algorithm.

I am looking for an efficient representation for the tableau, which consists of the undealt deck, the stacks, and the foundation.

For the deck, the most obvious representation is as a `[Card]` where `Card` is an algebraic data type:

```
data Rank = Ace
          | Two
          | Three
          | Four
          | Five
          | Six
          | Seven
          | Eight
          | Nine
          | Ten
          | Jack
          | Queen
          | King
          deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord)

data Suit = Clubs
          | Diamonds
          | Hearts
          | Spades
          deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord)

data Card = Card
  { rank   :: Rank
  , suit   :: Suit
  , faceUp :: Bool
  } deriving (Bounded, Eq, Ord)

-- I omitted the instance Show ... implementations
```

The foundation (the completed suits) can be represented as either a `[(Card King suit True)]` or simply an `Int` count of completed suits, since determining a winning game just requires confirming that the foundation size is 8.

The best representation for the stacks (the cards in play) is the part I am struggling with. If I were writing this in Scala or Clojure, I would probably use an immutable (persistent) `Vector` of `[Card]`. A vector allows fast indexed look up of the card lists for legal move calculation, using a list comprehension. The card lists are stored with the top card (facing up) as the head of the list. Moving cards from one list to another can be done with a combination of drop and prepend or cons.

In Haskell, I'm not sure if this is best represented as a list of card lists or an array of card lists, or some other data structure that I have not found yet.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AndrewC is correct that at this size you can use pretty much anything and it'll work well enough. Using lists everywhere is often a reasonable starting point, and a reasonable default. But I suspect you're also wanting to know what an idiomatic approach would be in Haskell, and indexing into a list is very rarely idiomatic (or a good idea at all).

For the collection of stacks you need indexed access; they're only a sequence incidentally. A [good default here would be `Data.IntMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-IntMap.html), which is a key-value collection represented by a trie, which means that lookup times are bounded by the size of the keys (hash tables have similar characteristics, since computing the hash function is also proportional to key size).

A minor annoyance with many possible structures here is that you have to check whether an index is a valid stack. As such, another option would be to create an enumerated type `data Stack = Stack1 | Stack2 | ...` and instead use `Data.Map`, which is a binary search tree, with `Stack` as keys and the collection of cards as the values. That way, every possible key is a valid stack, and as long as you initialized the `Map` first you can safely assume that any value you need exists.

Either `IntMap` or `Map` are vastly preferable to using a list of stacks, large tuples, or anything along those lines.

For the individual stacks, I'd actually consider storing them with the face-up card as the *last* element in the list--because you can move valid sequences of cards together, storing the cards in that order means you can simply swap tails between lists, rather than traverse and rebuild lists constantly.

Another option would be to represent the card sequences as a single value (suit, lowest card, highest card), which can then be moved around or split up later.

A more general purpose approach, that avoids the choice of list direction entirely, is [to use `Data.Sequence` instead](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html), which is a sequential (obviously) data structure with efficient operations on both ends.

Note that all three types I suggested come from the same package, which is a standard library, and usually the first place you should look for pure data structures if a list doesn't suit your needs.

---

**Edit:** An addendum on the subject of "vector" types: [The `vector` package used often in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) is a vector data structure in the usual sense of being a 1-dimensional array, with constant-time indexing, all-or-nothing updates for immutable `Vector`s, and some nice optimizations for vectors that are produced and consumed sequentially.

From what I can find, however, the "persistent vectors" used in Scala and Clojure are *not* simple immutable vectors in the usual sense; rather, they're a more sophisticated data structure designed to get as close as possible to the expected performance of *mutable* vectors in actual use. The actual implementation seems to be a trie with small arrays at each node; this is similar to `Data.IntMap`, but optimized for array-like use (many values in a limited range) rather than a key-value style of use (sparse data stored at arbitrary indices).

Comment: Excellent post, as usual. You're right, of course. When I first learned f.p., the list indexing operator in Orwell was `!`, which the lecturer called 'shriek', but in Haskell, it's `!!`, which I suppose many would call 'bang-bang'. Shriek is the sound the RTS makes when you ask for `[xs !! 5232,xs !! 324, xs!!3547]` and bang-bang is the sound the makes as it repeatedly clatters down your list.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. I will need to consider carefully which data structures I will use for both the stacks and the lists of card. I'll study the ones you mentioned.

Comment: @Ralph: I've edited the answer with a bit of extra information that might help relate my suggestions to what you'd use in Scala or Clojure.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the [`Vector` package](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell%3a_A_Vector_Tutorial) would be appropriate for your set of `[Card]`s. 
However, there are only a small number of piles so it doesn't matter - your application won't be unresponsive if you have to navigate through a list of length 8, so go with what you find preferable. I'm not sure it's all that crucial what you choose, given the small numbers.

Options:

- Vector - top choice, but you might decide it's overkill
- List - using `!!` etc. Not intractably slow for this purpose, familiar, but read C.A.McCann's answer. I ought not to lead you into bad habits!
- Direct use of Arrays
- Abstract data type `data Piles = Piles [Card] [Card] [Card] [Card] [Card] [Card] [Card] [Card]` - not very convenient
- Tuple `([Card],[Card],[Card],[Card],[Card],[Card],[Card],[Card])` - not very convenient

Comment: My first reaction on seeing your post was to use `Vector` -- that would be my choice in Scala or Clojure. Given C. A. McCann's answer, though, I'll have to consider carefully.

Comment: @Ralph: `Vector` is a good default choice if you need something that works well treated as either an array or a list. Replacing individual elements in an immutable array or `Vector` is relatively inefficient--they're best if you need to read individual elements by index, but perform mostly bulk updates. Note, by the way, that a `Vector` in Haskell is a different data structure from what Scala and Clojure call a vector.